# ASP.NET delete specific rows from gridview

Tags: asp.net, database, vb.net, checkbox

I need help  with following problem.
I try to delete specific rows from gridview.
Code bellow works well, but when page is loading its show all data in database.
How can I filter data? I mean when page is loading it shows nothing, but after type some text in text box, it shows me rows with that text and I can delete some of that rows with text from text box by check checkbox and button.

This is my code. Pls help me.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If IsPostBack Then
        GetData()
    End If
    BindGrid()
End Sub

Private Sub BindGrid()
    Dim constr As String = ConfigurationManager _
                .ConnectionStrings("conString").ConnectionString()
    Dim query As String = "select * from TestCustomers"
    Dim con As New SqlConnection(constr)
    Dim sda As New SqlDataAdapter(query, con)
    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    sda.Fill(dt)
    gvAll.DataSource = dt
    gvAll.DataBind()
End Sub

Protected Sub OnPaging(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewPageEventArgs)
    gvAll.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex
    gvAll.DataBind()
    SetData()
End Sub

Private Sub GetData()
    Dim arr As ArrayList
    If ViewState("SelectedRecords") IsNot Nothing Then
        arr = DirectCast(ViewState("SelectedRecords"), ArrayList)
    Else
        arr = New ArrayList()
    End If
    Dim chkAll As CheckBox = DirectCast(gvAll.HeaderRow _
                .Cells(0).FindControl("chkAll"), CheckBox)
    For i As Integer = 0 To gvAll.Rows.Count - 1
        If chkAll.Checked Then
            If Not arr.Contains(gvAll.DataKeys(i).Value) Then
                arr.Add(gvAll.DataKeys(i).Value)
            End If
        Else
            Dim chk As CheckBox = DirectCast(gvAll.Rows(i).Cells(0) _
                                        .FindControl("chk"), CheckBox)
            If chk.Checked Then
                If Not arr.Contains(gvAll.DataKeys(i).Value) Then
                    arr.Add(gvAll.DataKeys(i).Value)
                End If
            Else
                If arr.Contains(gvAll.DataKeys(i).Value) Then
                    arr.Remove(gvAll.DataKeys(i).Value)
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next
    ViewState("SelectedRecords") = arr
End Sub

Private Sub SetData()
    Dim currentCount As Integer = 0
    Dim chkAll As CheckBox = DirectCast(gvAll.HeaderRow _
                    .Cells(0).FindControl("chkAll"), CheckBox)
    chkAll.Checked = True
    Dim arr As ArrayList = DirectCast(ViewState("SelectedRecords") _
                                    , ArrayList)
    For i As Integer = 0 To gvAll.Rows.Count - 1
        Dim chk As CheckBox = DirectCast(gvAll.Rows(i).Cells(0) _
                                        .FindControl("chk"), CheckBox)
        If chk IsNot Nothing Then
            chk.Checked = arr.Contains(gvAll.DataKeys(i).Value)
            If Not chk.Checked Then
                chkAll.Checked = False
            Else
                currentCount += 1
            End If
        End If
    Next
    hfCount.Value = (arr.Count - currentCount).ToString()
End Sub

Protected Sub btnDelete_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim count As Integer = 0
    SetData()
    gvAll.AllowPaging = False
    gvAll.DataBind()
    Dim arr As ArrayList = DirectCast(ViewState("SelectedRecords") _
                                , ArrayList)
    count = arr.Count
    For i As Integer = 0 To gvAll.Rows.Count - 1
        If arr.Contains(gvAll.DataKeys(i).Value) Then
            DeleteRecord(gvAll.DataKeys(i).Value.ToString())
            arr.Remove(gvAll.DataKeys(i).Value)
        End If
    Next
    ViewState("SelectedRecords") = arr
    hfCount.Value = "0"
    gvAll.AllowPaging = True
    BindGrid()
    ShowMessage(count)
End Sub

Private Sub DeleteRecord(ByVal CustomerID As String)
    Dim constr As String = ConfigurationManager _
                    .ConnectionStrings("conString").ConnectionString
    Dim query As String = "delete from TestCustomers where" & _
                            " CustomerID=@CustomerID"
    Dim con As New SqlConnection(constr)
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(query, con)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerID", CustomerID)
    con.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub ShowMessage(ByVal count As Integer)
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
    sb.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>")
    sb.Append("alert('")
    sb.Append(count.ToString())
    sb.Append(" records deleted.');")
    sb.Append("</script>")
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), _
                    "script", sb.ToString())
End Sub

<asp:GridView ID="gvAll" runat="server" 
    AutoGenerateColumns = "false" Font-Names = "Arial" 
    Font-Size = "11pt" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor = "#C2D69B"  
    HeaderStyle-BackColor = "green" AllowPaging ="true"   
    OnPageIndexChanging = "OnPaging" DataKeyNames = "CustomerID"
    PageSize = "10" >
   <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkAll" runat="server" onclick = "checkAll(this);" />
        </HeaderTemplate> 
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chk" runat="server" onclick = "Check_Click(this)"/>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField> 
    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width = "150px" DataField = "ContactName" HeaderText = "Contact Name"/>
    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width = "150px" DataField = "Country" HeaderText = "Country"/>
    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width = "150px" DataField = "City" HeaderText = "City"/>
   </Columns> 
   <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#C2D69B"  />
</asp:GridView> 
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hfCount" runat="server" Value = "0" />
    <asp:Button ID="btnDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete Checked Records" OnClientClick = "return ConfirmDelete();" OnClick="btnDelete_Click" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though your question is not clear , i will answer what i have understood.

you want to show all data on page load and on postback you want to show selected rows , right ?

if yes

try this code 
  If IsPostBack Then
        GetData()
    End If

else
    BindGrid()

if this has not answered your question , please tell me what exactly you want to do.

Comment: thank you.i mean when page is loading..datagrid is empty. so not show..after input text in text box then click search button ,all record with text from text box will show up..then i simply choose specific records that i want to delete and click delete button to delete selected rows..in my code  all rows show when page is loading..but i want to choose rows that i want to delete  with specific text...not from all records as now..

Answer (score 0):

This will delete all rows that had been selected.

```
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In yourDGV.SelectedRows
    yourDGV.Rows.Remove(row)
Next


Private Sub btndelete_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btndelete.Click
  If DataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0 Then
   DataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index)
  Else
   MessageBox.Show("You must select a row")
  End If
End Sub
```

**Use this it may help full to you**

```
Protected Sub btnDelete_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    For Each gvrow As GridViewRow In gvDetails.Rows
        'Finiding checkbox control in gridview for particular row
        Dim chkdelete As CheckBox = DirectCast(gvrow.FindControl("chkSelect"), CheckBox)
        'Condition to check checkbox selected or not
        If chkdelete.Checked Then
            'Getting UserId of particular row using datakey value
            Dim usrid As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(gvDetails.DataKeys(gvrow.RowIndex).Value)
            Using con As New SqlConnection("YOUR SQL DATABASE CONNECTION")
                con.Open()
                Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("delete from UserDetails where UserId=" & usrid, con)
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                con.Close()
            End Using
        End If
    Next
    BindUserDetails()
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you for your code...but i want to delete rows by select them by checkbix and click button to delete selected rows

Comment: you should not bind all the rows on page load, on page loading you have to show the empty grid, write the query to search the text from SQL table and execute the query, now show the result on grid with check boxes. Now which record do you want to delete select and click on the delete button .